# Square Roots: How to Go on after getting to 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's my problem, labelled #2. I left off because I didn't know what to do next. Any tips, clues, hints and answers would be appreciated. Here's an image.

[image]

Comment: Have you studied quadratic equations, discriminant, roots formula (or Viete's formulas)...something?

Comment: A bit, I have an assignment on it which is this problem of few but I don't get where to continue. Algebra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$3x^2+8x-3=0$

$(3x-1)(x+3)=0$

$3x-1=0$ or $x+3=0$

$x=\frac13$ or $x=-3$

Comment: Awesome! Perfect, thanks. Get it now. My question to you is this" in something like(3x−1)(x+3)=0 doesn't it have to add to one number and multiply to the other? 3 x 1 is definitely 3, but nothing adds or multiplies to 8 -- unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You mean 3 and 8? Most probably, but I'm drawing a blank right now. I get confused with the term product. Does that mean what goes into 3 and 8?

Comment: @user1925224 The guideline you're thinking of works when one has $x^2$, but not when there's a multiple of $x^2$.

Comment: The missing step is finding 2 numbers that multiply to -9 and add up to 8 which would be -9 and 1.

Answer (score 4):

You can always resort to using the quadratic formula:

For a quadratic equation of the form $ax^2 + bx+ c = 0$,

the real solutions (roots) (if there are such solutions) are given by $$x = \dfrac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

In your equation, we have $a = 3,\;b = 8,\;c = -3$.

Comment: That's a little too confusing for me, but nonetheless, thanks a lot for the input! I appreciate that. Am I not allowed to go forward with the method I was using?

Comment: This is going forward with the method you were using. By getting a 0 on one side, you put the problem into a quadratic equation of the form ax² + bx + c = 0.

Answer (score 2):

The whole reason of writing it with a $0$ on one side is to take advantage of the fact that if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $ab = 0$, then $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

In particular, notice that we can factor

$$3x^2 + 8x - 3 = (3x - 1)(x + 3)$$